# C - deleting n-ary tree nodes

Tags: c, tree, n-ary-tree

I have implemented in C an m,n,k-game with AI. The game works fine but when I have to free the decision tree it always throws an "Access violation reading location" exception.

This is the implementation of the decision tree structure:

```
typedef struct decision_tree_s {
    unsigned short **board;
    status_t status;
    struct decision_tree_s *brother;
    struct decision_tree_s *children;
} decision_tree_t;
```

And this is the implementation of the `delete_tree` function:

```
void delete_tree(decision_tree_t **tree) {
    decision_tree_t *tmp;

    if (*tree != NULL) {
        delete_tree((*tree)->children);
        delete_tree((*tree)->brother);

        free(*tree);
        *tree = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited the delete tree function back as it was at the beginning of the project and now the tree deletion seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are destroying twice the `children` member: first time in the `for` loop, the second time after the loop.

You might want to write your for loop like that:

```
for (tmp = tree->brother; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->brother) {
    delete_tree(tmp);
}
```